# jquery.validate addMethod error displays even true is retained

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

**I am using additional method for checking capcha validation using jquery.validate**

```
 $.validator.addMethod("ajax_validation", function(value) {
  var ajax_data='ajax_mode=capcha_validation&code='+value;
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/app/ajax_validation/",
      data: ajax_data,
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(msg){
    if(msg=='true')
    {
     alert('true');
     return true;
    }
    else
    {
     alert('false');
     return false;
    }

      }
   });
 }, 'Please enter code correctly!');
```

Even when i retain true value error is always displayed on screen how to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to catch the result and go any further, you need to call jquery ajax in sync format. In your code, whatever the result is, the default behavior (which should be an error message, I think) happens.
Don't forget that jQuery Ajax call are Async by default ("A" from "Async" is Asynchronous) and if you want to do ajax call in sync manner, you need to do turn it to 'false' like this:
(I put your method in a separate function for clarity)

```
    function ajax_validation(ajax_data) {
          var ajax_data='ajax_mode=capcha_validation&code='+value;          
          var result;
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              async: false,
              url: "/app/ajax_validation/",
              data: ajax_data,
              dataType: "text",
              success: function(msg){
                     result= msg.d;
               }  
           });
           return result; 
    }     
        //...
```

*However, note that ajax Sync calls may freeze the browser and generally is not a good practice.*

Comment: I can retrive value from ajax also i need to close the displaying error. Even for true case also error is displaying

Comment: In this case, retrieving the result from ajax is not the matter, it's about being sync or asyn; in both scenarios you will get the result correctly, but generally speaking, javascript interpreter doesn't wait for your result in async case and it immediately goes to the next statements. Of course I dont' have other parts of your code logic; this is what I can guess from your code shot above.

Comment: when i returns true i should not want to display error in jquery.validate addMethod.